# c++ Iterator debug behavior very different for string and vector

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, iterator

I have come across some issues with c++ iterator debugging and noticed that the behavior in debug build is very different for string and vector in a way I'd consider bad and against my expectation.

Note: I am compiling with MSVC under Windows.

When I iterate over a container (string or vector) and perform certain operations like erase, replace the iterate can become invalid. If you continue to iterate over the container in Visual Studio a dialog will pop up, because some iterator debug verifications have been violated. This is what I expect to happen in such situations.

The following code does throw for the vector, but not for the string. My expectation would be, that it does throw for both!

```
void force_string_crash()
{
    std::string stuff = "foobarfoo";
    for (auto it = stuff.begin(); it != stuff.end(); ++it)
    {
    if (*it == 'b')
    {
        stuff.erase(it);
    }
    }
}

void force_vector_crash()
{
    std::vector<int> stuff = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for (auto it = stuff.begin(); it != stuff.end(); ++it)
    {
    if (*it == 3)
    {
        stuff.erase(it);
    }
    }
}

int main()
{
    force_string_crash();
    force_vector_crash();

    return 0;
}
```

In my understanding reallocation of the underlying memory is a cause for invalidating iterators, however erasing a single element of a vector should not perform any reallocation, yet does throw (and subsequently check some invalidation criteria!). String doesn't.

My original issue was this same problem, but with string.replace, i.e. instead of erase you can do:

```
stuff.replace(it, it + 1, replace_content)
```

Then it does get even more weird! As long as replace_content is of size <8 the iterator seems to stay valid and everything is fine. Upwards of 7 characters the iterator becomes invalid.

Important note: If the iterator becomes invalid in Visual Studio I get an actual dialog with  cancel, repeat, ignore buttons. This dialog pops up, when I get invalid iterators. In the case that I erase an element from the vector while iterating over it I do not get that dialog, because while checking a condition to verify iterator integrity a nullptr occures and it breaks there. This is a subtle difference I can't explain as well.

Comment: You are in undefined behavior land.  The output of both functions are "correct" as they are allowed to have any behavior.

Comment: Your expectations, unfortunately, are incorrect. This is undefined behavior. The C++ standard does not require undefined behavior to result in a nice popup, no matter what compilation configuration wad used. The results of undefined behavior are undefined.

Comment: Here is what Visual Studio is telling you: *"In debug mode, we will help you as best as we can, but there is no guarantee if we can help with every scenario -- in other words, you need to fix your code"*.

Comment: Perhaps they just didn't implement debug iterators for `std::string` and the iterator is just a `char*`. In that case it'll most likely stay valid after the `erase`. Try putting a `b` last in the string.

Comment: you never get a guaranteed crash. A crash is the result of undefined behavior where anything can happen. Also iterator invalidation does not mean that there would be a guarantee that the iterator is invalid. It means that there is no guarantee that the iterator is valid. Those two are very different statements, the latter does not imply the first but you assume that it does

Comment: Not sure if small string optimization is still possible for your string, but it could possibly make a difference for checks...

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am aware that this UB land and I do not expect any guarantees about the program behavior, but I was simply in believe the debug support would be greater here. But like some of you stated it's most likely a "as best as we can" situation.
I have tried the same with g++ and it behaves the same. The throw in vector is guaranteed, but within string the iterator invalidation "is fine". The guarantee about no guarantee that the iterator is valid makes a lot of sense to me.